# Is there an information-theoretic motivation for heat kernel weights on adjacency graph?

Tags: differential-geometry, information-theory, heat-equation, graph-laplacian

I am learning about the [laplacian eigenmap](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6789755) algorithm for finding a lower dimensional representation of a dataset. An important step in this algorithm is assigning weights to the adjacency graph for the data by using the heat kernel,
$$w_{ij} = \Bigg\lbrace \begin{array}{ll}e^{-\frac{|x_i-x_j|^2}{t}} & \text{if $i$ is adjacent to $j$} \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{array}$$I'm trying to understand the motivations for this weight choice.

My question here is very general: Is there any value developing intuition for this problem through the lens of information theory? In learning a lower-dimensional representation of the data set, is there a notion of entropy/ignorance that one wants to maximise subject to this constraint? Some sort of Gibbs measure would be the maximally-entropic measure to use as weights on the graph, and indeed the heat kernel $w_{ij}$ has the same form as a Gibbs measure, with energy measured by the distance between points, $|x_i-x_j|$. Larger distances between points would then correspond to larger entropy/ignorance, which makes sense from the perspective that it's harder to find a good projection between points further away.

If this has any validity, I'd appreciate any answers expanding on this train of thought with more rigour or references.

Comment: It is explained in some detail in sec. 3 that the form of the weights arises through 1) an analysis of an optimal embedding objective for manifolds, which gives rise to the Laplace-Beltrami operator, and 2) through the fact that the heat kernel arises naturally when studying the behaviour of this operator. Algorithmically, the nodes $x_i$ are seen as a discrete sampling of a manifold, and the authors want want to construct an operator on it that looks like a discretisation of the Laplace-Beltrami operator, which naturally leads to this weight.

Comment: Now, I'm not aware of this, but there may well be information theoretic interpretations of the heat kernel, which you can maybe turn to (and which would indeed be interesting to see), but as far as the paper is concerned, the intuition is geometric. Also see the field of spectral graph theory.